# Vulnerability Tracking Site

Tags: kali-linux

my ask is really simple.

I have a group that do ethical hacking, we search vulnerabilities on webpages, analize them, and make the proper paper to inform the organization involved.

We are having a rough time tracking what we found, is there any service (mountable website) that allows you to keep track of the finding (files, links, images, texts, etc...) and be collaborative?

Thanks in advance!
We are fighting for a more secure internet.

PD: English is not my nat

Comment: Welcome to our site. I hate to be discouraging, but product recommendations in general tend to be off-topic. Particularly in you're case, what you're looking for is a general collaboration tool. That you will is used for security work is tangental to that. Hopefully Rory McCune's answer will be helpful to you, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you take a look at the [Dradis Framework](http://dradisframework.org/).  It's a collaborative tool designed for primarily for security testing, so it may well fit your needs.

Comment: Testing it right now.